# How to handle time.time() in Python?

Tags: python, datetime, timestamp

I'm trying to collect real-time data with `hdf5`, but it doesn't support `datetime` for now, so I thought `np.float64(timestamp)` would be a better option than simple strings, from the standpoint of storage efficiency(8bits vs more than 8 bits). I want to record event times with microsecond precision.

From these web pages(https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html, https://pymotw.com/2/time/index.html), I read that timestamps that I get by `time.time()` is calculated in UTC, but now I think something's different from what I read.

```
from datetime import datetime
import time

print( datetime.utcnow() )

print( datetime.fromtimestamp( time.time() ) )

>>> (executing file "<tmp 2>")
2018-03-16 21:28:34.716853
2018-03-17 06:28:34.716854
```

I don't understand why they are different. If timestamps are calculated in UTC, I think they should be the same.

I have another question. I'd like to know how to add some amount of time to timestamps. For example, I want to know how to do this with timestamps.

```
datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(hours=3)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`datetime.utcnow()` is the utc time, [`datetime.fromtimestamp()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.fromtimestamp) is the local time, which depends on your time zone.

To add to timestamp, you just need to convert the `timedelta` to seconds:

```
time.time() + timedelta(hours=3).total_seconds()
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Is there any way to convert ```timestamp``` to ```datetime in UTC ```?

Comment: @maynull https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp